# mysqld fails to start due to InnoDB

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

I did install MariaDB on MX Linux, my system info below :

```
System:    Kernel: 5.10.0-9-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64 
           root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm 4.16.1 vt: 7 
           dm: LightDM 1.26.0 Distro: MX-21_x64 Wildflower October 20  2021 
           base: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

When I start the server using the command :

sudo mysqld

I get the following error regarding InnoDB missing FILE_CHECKPOINT :

```
$ sudo mysqld
[sudo] password for ****: 
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.12-MariaDB-0+deb11u1) starting as process 14306 ...
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: 2 column families found
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: Column Families at start:
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]   cf=default
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     write_buffer_size=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     target_file_size_base=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]   cf=__system__
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     write_buffer_size=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     target_file_size_base=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: Table_store: loaded DDL data for 0 tables
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: global statistics using get_sched_indexer_t indexer
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] MyRocks storage engine plugin has been successfully initialized.
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=45118,45118
**2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT at 45118 between the checkpoint 45118 and the end 108246.**
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It is beyond my competences, can anyone give me some hint ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint

Comment: But read the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB could indeed not recover from the last logfile named :   ib_logfile0

As I didn't need to save anything, I did simply remove

/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0

after what I have been able to start the server normally.

PS : I am new here, and I didn't know if I should user "answer my question" or just mention this in a "comment".

Comment: Answering it was the right choice. Don't forget to accept your answer when you are allowed to, otherwise the question stays in the system as "unanswered" forever.

Comment: How did you trace this to that exact file?

Comment: This should [never be done again](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-errors-cant-start-mariadb-after-unexpected-shutdown/).